# Dont understand how i get the result

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

PHP Help
Please could you try to explain this to me, it occurs when am making a website with the right result but I can't figure out how the result is true

```
enter <title><?php echo $user_session; $age = 2015 - $sql_user_info['dateofbirth']; echo " ".$age;?> | OCRCSITE</title> here
```

I am trying to get the user's age and I succeed but I can't figure the how the result is right, when the age in the database is 1996-01-22
Please I will be glad if you could explain.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share a little more about what you're trying to do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the way PHP casts strings to numbers. The string `"1996-01-22"` is evaluated to the number `1996`. Thus, `2015 - 1996 = 19`. More information can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: No problem! This link might also be helpful: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion